# conversion of xaml textbox code to c# textbox code?

Tags: c#, xaml

I have developed an Text Box with XAML code, but now i need to convert it in to C# Code;
but I'm not familiar with it. So, Hereby I am sharing my code, and i request you all to convert it into C# code;

My XAML Code;

```
<TextBox Name="txt1" Height="72" Width="130" Margin="193,3,0,0" InputScope="Number" MaxLength="3"/>
<TextBox Name="txt2" Height="72" Width="130" Margin="193,68,0,0" InputScope="Number" MaxLength="3"/>
```

I created TextBox by c# code `TextBox txt1 = new TextBox()`. But i dunno how to create textbox with above XAML TextBox Properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this..

```
 TextBlock txt1 = new TextBlock();
        txt1.Height = 72;
        txt1.Width = 72;
        txt1.Margin = new Thickness(193, 3, 0, 0);
        InputScope inputScope = new InputScope();
        InputScopeName inputScopeName = new InputScopeName();
        inputScopeName.NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.Number;

        inputScope.Names.Add(inputScopeName);
        txt1.InputScope = inputScope;
        SomeGrid.Children.Add(txt1); // somegrid is a parent control in which you wanted to add your textblock
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply drag and drop from toolbox. However, You can do it like this via code.

```
System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt1 = = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
txt1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(78, 183);
this.txt1.MaxLength = 3;
this.txt1.Multiline = true;
this.txt1.Name = "txt1";
this.txt1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(130, 72);
this.txt1.TabIndex = 2;
this.Controls.Add(this.txt1);
```

Now InputScope = Number

There are couple of ways here. You can use **MaskedTextBox** or you can **restrict user** by validating his input. First one is the preferred.

```
System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox txt1= new System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox();
this.txt1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(149, 141);
this.txt1.Mask = "000";
this.txt1.Name = "txt1";
this.txt1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
this.txt1.TabIndex = 3;
this.txt1.ValidatingType = typeof(int);
this.Controls.Add(this.txt1);
```

Comment: You are right But `InputScope="Number"` is missing. I need that also. User should enter only number not words

Answer (score 0):

You can create the TextBox the same way you have mentioned and then you can set the properties. Something like

```
TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
tx1.Name = "tx1";
```

You should be able to set most of the properties like this. For few complex properties you may have to create an instance of some type and then set it.

Comment: You are right But `InputScope="Number"` is missing. I need that also. User should enter only number not words

Comment: Like I said, for few properties you have to create instance of a type